# How to Resolve 'Maximum Call Stack Exceeded' Error when Using 'useClient' in Component?

Tags: typescript, next.js, error-handling, infinite-loop

I'm working on a Next.js application, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to use the useClient hook within one of my components. Whenever I include useClient in my component, I receive a "Maximum call stack exceeded" error, which seems to indicate some form of recursion or infinite loop.

```
    "use client"
import { serverPropsWithMembers } from "@/types"
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuSeparator,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu"
import { ChevronDown, LogOut, PlusCircle, Settings, Trash, UserPlus, Users } from 'lucide-react'
import { Role } from "@/Models/schema-models"
import { useModel } from "@/app/hooks/use-model-store"


interface serverHeaderProps{
    server:serverPropsWithMembers,
    role?:Role
}
const ServerHeader = ({
    server,
    role
}:serverHeaderProps) => {
  const { onOpen  } = useModel()

  const isAdmin = role === Role.ADMIN
  const isModerator = isAdmin || role === Role.MODERATOR
  
 
  
  return (
    <DropdownMenu>
    <DropdownMenuTrigger className="focus:outline-none" asChild>
      <button className="h-12 w-full text-md px-3 font-semibold bg-neutral-200 dark:bg-neutral-800 hover:bg-zinc-900/10 dark:hover:bg-zinc-900/50 flex items-center border-b-2">
        {server.name}
        <ChevronDown className="h-5 w-5 ml-auto"/>
      </button>
    </DropdownMenuTrigger>
    <DropdownMenuContent className="text-xs font-medium w-56 items-center text-black space-y-[2px] dark:text-neutral-400 ">
      {isModerator && (
      <DropdownMenuItem 
      onClick={()=> onOpen('invite',{server})}
      className="px-3 py-2 text-sm cursor-pointer">
        Invite People
        <UserPlus className='h-4 w-5 ml-auto'/>
      </DropdownMenuItem>
      )}
      {isAdmin && (
      <DropdownMenuItem className=" px-3 py-2 text-sm cursor-pointer">
        Server settings 
        <Settings className='h-4 w-4 ml-auto'/>
      </DropdownMenuItem>
      )}
      {isAdmin && (
      <DropdownMenuItem className=" px-3 py-2 text-sm cursor-pointer">
        Manage Members
        <Users className='h-4 w-4 ml-auto'/>
      </DropdownMenuItem>
      )}
      {isAdmin && (
      <DropdownMenuItem className=" px-3 py-2 text-sm cursor-pointer">
         create Channel
        <PlusCircle className='h-4 w-4 ml-auto'/>
      </DropdownMenuItem>
      )}
      {isModerator && (
      <DropdownMenuItem className="px-3 py-2 text-sm cursor-pointer">
        <DropdownMenuSeparator className='dark:bg-zinc-600 w-full rounded-md'/>
      </DropdownMenuItem>
      )}
       {isAdmin && (
      <DropdownMenuItem className="text-rose-500 px-3 py-2 text-sm cursor-pointer">
         Delete Server
        <Trash className='h-4 w-4 ml-auto '/>
      </DropdownMenuItem>
      )}
       {!isAdmin && (
      <DropdownMenuItem className="text-rose-500 px-3 py-2 text-sm cursor-pointer">
         Leave Server
        <LogOut className='h-4 w-4 ml-auto '/>
      </DropdownMenuItem>
      )}

    </DropdownMenuContent>
  </DropdownMenu>
  
  )
}

export default ServerHeader
```

The error goes when I don't use the "use client" But I need "use client" here because of useModel Hook. So does anyone know How I can fix this issue in my next js file? I also checked all the dependencies, there are not any conflicts between dependencies that can cause recursion.
Here is hook file :

```
  import { create } from 'zustand'
import { Server } from '@/Models/schema-models';
import { serverPropsWithMembers } from '@/types';

export type ModelType = "createServer" | "invite" 

interface ModelData {
   server?:serverPropsWithMembers
}

interface ModelStore {
    type: ModelType | null;
    data:ModelData;
    isOpen: boolean;
    onOpen: (type:ModelType,data?: ModelData) => void;
    onClose: () => void;
}

export const useModel = create<ModelStore>((set)=>({
    type :null,
    data:{},
    isOpen:false,
    onOpen:(type,data={}) => set({isOpen:true,type,data}),
    onClose:() => set({isOpen:false,type:null})
}))
```

here is the serverWithMembers types file :

```
import { IMember, IServer, IUser } from "./Models/schema-models"

export type serverPropsWithMembers = IServer & {
members:IMember & {
  UserProfile : IUser
}}
```

and here is the Schema files

```
 import mongoose, { Schema, Types, model, models } from 'mongoose';


export interface IUser {
userId:string,
name:string,
email:string,
imageUrl:string,
server:Types.ObjectId[],
members:Types.ObjectId[],
channels:Types.ObjectId[]
}

const UserProfileSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
    userId: { type: String, unique: true },
    name: String,
    email: {type:String,index:true , unique:true},
    imageUrl: {type: String,index:true},
    
    server:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Server'}],
    members:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Members'}],
    channels:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Channels'}]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const UserProfile  = models?.['UserProfile'] || model<IUser>('UserProfile', UserProfileSchema);






export interface IServer {
name:string,
imageUrl:string,
inviteCode:string,
profileId:Types.ObjectId,
channels:Types.ObjectId[],
members:Types.ObjectId[]
}

const serverSchema = new Schema<IServer>({
    name: String,
    imageUrl: { type: String, index: true },
    inviteCode: { type: String, unique: true },

    profileId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserProfile', index: true },
    channels:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Channels'}],
    members:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Members'}],
    
},{
    timestamps:true
});

const Server = models?.['Server'] || model<IServer>('Server', serverSchema);



export interface IMember {
    role: Role;
    profileId: Types.ObjectId;
    servers: Types.ObjectId[];
  }
  
  export enum Role {
    ADMIN = 'ADMIN',
    MODERATOR = 'MODERATOR',
    GUEST = 'GUEST',
  }
  
  const MemberSchema = new Schema<IMember>({
    role: { type: String, default: Role.GUEST, enum: Object.values(Role), index: true },
    profileId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', index: true },
    servers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Server' }],
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
  });
  
const Members = models?.['Members'] ||  model<IMember>("Members",MemberSchema)





export interface IChannel {
    name:string,
    type:ChannelType,
    profileId:Types.ObjectId,
    server:Types.ObjectId[]
}

 export enum ChannelType {
    TEXT = 'TEXT',
    VIDEO = 'VIDEO',
    AUDIO = 'AUDIO'
}

const ChannelSchema  = new Schema<IChannel>({
    name:String,
    type:{ type: String , default:ChannelType.TEXT,required:true,enum:Object.values(ChannelType),index:true},

    profileId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserProfile', index: true },
    server:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Server'}]
},{
    timestamps:true
})


const Channels = models?.['Channels']||  model<IChannel>("Channels",ChannelSchema)





export { UserProfile, Server , Members , Channels };
```

Comment: Share the code for `useModel`

Comment: sure @RobinThomas I edited my question,Now you can see the useModel in this code!

Comment: Where is the `useClient` hook?

Comment: @RobinThomas I am using next, the use client hook is coming from nextjs and useModels is not a component it is a store for managing the state so it is not using use client hook, server header is using "use client hook" and it is defined at the first line of server header.My component works fine when I don't use the use client hook on the server header, But I need to use "use client " here when I use the useModel hook because it use client side rendering that Is when I get the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: I have spent countless hours to fix this issue but nothing seems to work. If you could help, it would be a great help. If you want to review the full code here is my repo: [https://github.com/AbdullahZafar327/Discord-Server] Thanks @RobinThomas

Comment: @RobinThomas I noticed the issue is with how I define the server types on the server Header. Do you know how I can correct these mistakes based on the server data I am receiving from the server sidebar as props.I tried to fix this issue but they are not working.I don't know why , the types seem right to me.

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get this error: `Missing Clerk Secret Key or API Key. Go to https://dashboard.clerk.com and get your key for your instance.`

Comment: @RobinThomas that's because I didn't push my secret keys to the repo due to security concerns , I am using clerk for authentication so you can get you secret key easily!

Comment: @AbdullahDeveloper, have you resolved your issue? I am facing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Fix:
I had a similar issue, where the 'Maximum Call Stack Exceeded' error occurred when I was passing data retrieved from MongoDB to another component's prop. However, when I passed 'mock data' that I defined within my code instead of retrieving from the database, the error disappeared.

The error was occurring because I was trying to pass 'comment' objects with their MongoDB-given _id's included. Once I 'cleaned' the data and removed the _id's from being included within the 'comment' objects that were passed to the other component's prop, then the error was fixed.

My explanation has many terms that are unique to my code, but I hope that it can help someone else who encounters this error in the future – as the 'Maximum Call Stack Exceeded' error really gave no direction as to what the actual error was, and I still don't know why that was the particular error displayed.

The moral I gained from the story: **clean/inspect your data.**

Answer (score -1):

It seems that newer versions of Next JS have an issue with passing some type of elements (props) between client and server components. Given the case you're using MongoDB, you'll have to make sure you're correctly de-structuring query results that contain **ObjectId** data types, this will cause many errors, including the one you're describing. There are two ways I recommend to solve the issue:

1. Using JSON.stringify(data) to turn the data into a plain text, so that there aren't any issues when sending down props between server/client components.
2. Taking the time to specify what is the content of the result data from each database query, specially if you're using Typescript. For example, instead of sending the entire retrieved data of an author down to a component and then trying to access each piece of the author information from within the component receiving the data, de-structure the data object and send the specific author information that the component will need.

To summarize, try to clean up and organize the data you receive from the backend instead of sending it raw to your components/pages.

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.